# Swift: Bottom constraint to screen in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

Alright so I have this screen which is entirely boxed in a UIScrollView. The concern here is that I want the "Continue" button to be touching the bottom of the device (not the scrollview's bottom) and scroll rest of the part below it. When I set the bottom constraint to 0, its automatically taken to the end of scrollview since it's the child. How can I set the margin in a way that its always at the bottom of device's screen rather than at the bottom of UIScrollview. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: If you want continue button to stay at a fixed position, why don't you move it out of scrollview and contraint it according to the super view (or safearea)?

Comment: @MumtazHussain but then it won't scroll at all and only text below it would come up. I need to settle it at device bottom but also be scrollable.

Comment: You can create a container view for all the elements till continue button. Set this view height same as device height and keep continue button at the bottom of this view. Now add this view and the rest of labels/button etc inside the scrollview to get the result you wanted.

Comment: Perfect, I took the overall picture from your statement and made it work by keeping equal heights with the main view while keeping my container view inside the scroll view. Thanks a lot @Kamran